# GTK Drawing Area Widget does not show in window using TinyCore

Tags: linux, gtk, gtk3

I am just starting out in using both TinyCore Linux and GTK+3 and am reading through and trying a bunch of different tutorials. I am trying the sample code from the GTK website (https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s03.html) and it is not working.  I am able to compile, with one warning popping up:

*warning: 'gdk_window_get_pointer' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkwindow.h:837): Use 'gdk_window_get_device_position' instead [-Wdeprecated-declaration]*

When I run the program the window pops up, but there is no drawing area. I took the same code and compiled it on an Ubuntu machine and it worked just fine, it didn't even show the warning about the depreciated function.  Any ideas about what may be causing the drawing area to not display would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for taking the time to read this far.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

/* Surface to store current scribbles */
static cairo_surface_t *surface = NULL;

static void
clear_surface (void)
{
  cairo_t *cr;

  cr = cairo_create (surface);

  cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 1, 1, 1);
  cairo_paint (cr);

  cairo_destroy (cr);
}

/* Create a new surface of the appropriate size to store our scribbles */
static gboolean
configure_event_cb (GtkWidget         *widget,
                    GdkEventConfigure *event,
                    gpointer           data)
{
  if (surface)
    cairo_surface_destroy (surface);

  surface = gdk_window_create_similar_surface (gtk_widget_get_window (widget),
                                               CAIRO_CONTENT_COLOR,
                                               gtk_widget_get_allocated_width (widget),
                                               gtk_widget_get_allocated_height (widget));

  /* Initialize the surface to white */
  clear_surface ();

  /* We've handled the configure event, no need for further processing. */
  return TRUE;
}

/* Redraw the screen from the surface. Note that the ::draw
 * signal receives a ready-to-be-used cairo_t that is already
 * clipped to only draw the exposed areas of the widget
 */
static gboolean
draw_cb (GtkWidget *widget,
         cairo_t   *cr,
         gpointer   data)
{
  cairo_set_source_surface (cr, surface, 0, 0);
  cairo_paint (cr);

  return FALSE;
}

/* Draw a rectangle on the surface at the given position */
static void
draw_brush (GtkWidget *widget,
            gdouble    x,
            gdouble    y)
{
  cairo_t *cr;

  /* Paint to the surface, where we store our state */
  cr = cairo_create (surface);

  cairo_rectangle (cr, x - 3, y - 3, 6, 6);
  cairo_fill (cr);

  cairo_destroy (cr);

  /* Now invalidate the affected region of the drawing area. */
  gtk_widget_queue_draw_area (widget, x - 3, y - 3, 6, 6);
}

/* Handle button press events by either drawing a rectangle
 * or clearing the surface, depending on which button was pressed.
 * The ::button-press signal handler receives a GdkEventButton
 * struct which contains this information.
 */
static gboolean
button_press_event_cb (GtkWidget      *widget,
                       GdkEventButton *event,
                       gpointer        data)
{
  /* paranoia check, in case we haven't gotten a configure event */
  if (surface == NULL)
    return FALSE;

  if (event->button == GDK_BUTTON_PRIMARY)
    {
      draw_brush (widget, event->x, event->y);
    }
  else if (event->button == GDK_BUTTON_SECONDARY)
    {
      clear_surface ();
      gtk_widget_queue_draw (widget);
    }

  /* We've handled the event, stop processing */
  return TRUE;
}

/* Handle motion events by continuing to draw if button 1 is
 * still held down. The ::motion-notify signal handler receives
 * a GdkEventMotion struct which contains this information.
 */
static gboolean
motion_notify_event_cb (GtkWidget      *widget,
                        GdkEventMotion *event,
                        gpointer        data)
{
  /* paranoia check, in case we haven't gotten a configure event */
  if (surface == NULL)
    return FALSE;

  if (event->state & GDK_BUTTON1_MASK)
    draw_brush (widget, event->x, event->y);

  /* We've handled it, stop processing */
  return TRUE;
}

static void
close_window (void)
{
  if (surface)
    cairo_surface_destroy (surface);

  gtk_main_quit ();
}

int
main (int   argc,
      char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *frame;
  GtkWidget *da;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Drawing Area");

  g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (close_window), NULL);

  gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 8);

  frame = gtk_frame_new (NULL);
  gtk_frame_set_shadow_type (GTK_FRAME (frame), GTK_SHADOW_IN);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), frame);

  da = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
  /* set a minimum size */
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (da, 100, 100);

  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (frame), da);

  /* Signals used to handle the backing surface */
  g_signal_connect (da, "draw",
                    G_CALLBACK (draw_cb), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (da,"configure-event",
                    G_CALLBACK (configure_event_cb), NULL);

  /* Event signals */
  g_signal_connect (da, "motion-notify-event",
                    G_CALLBACK (motion_notify_event_cb), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (da, "button-press-event",
                    G_CALLBACK (button_press_event_cb), NULL);

  /* Ask to receive events the drawing area doesn't normally
   * subscribe to. In particular, we need to ask for the
   * button press and motion notify events that want to handle.
   */
  gtk_widget_set_events (da, gtk_widget_get_events (da)
                             | GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK
                             | GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);

  gtk_main ();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that the above code works just fine on Fedora 20 / Cinnamon with gtk+ 3.10.9 without spawning any warnings.

Comment: @drahnr thanks for taking the time to look at the code

Answer (score 0):

I did a fresh install and the warning message disappeared, but the drawing area still refused to show up.  I eventually tried changing from the default color depth to 16 bit color depth using the boot code "xvesa=1280x1024x16" and it started showing up.  I assume this means it was a driver issue, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Possibly, cairo_t tries to (afaik) use *some* hardware capabilites to copy surfaces. If your driver is buggy, i.e. advertises some cap but does not handle it properly, this may happen.